# run SharePoint management shell with c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell

I have some ps1 that I need to run it with SharePoint management shell.
I dont have the possibility to run it with the traditionnal powershell even i havce the administrator role :

```
  public string Runps1()
    {
        try
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
                powerShell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted");
                powerShell.AddScript(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Data_tier\PS1\STSadm_PreUpgrade.ps1");

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (PSObject obj in powerShell.Invoke())
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

                }


                runspace.Close();

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp) { throw; }
    }
```

I know that this code is for traditionnal Power Shell , There is any idea for SharePoint management shell.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/11/14/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add PowerShell snap-in in you .ps1 file. But in this case you should have some permissions to sql and SharePoint

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

Comment: thanks Andrey ,It works for me , but I just can inderstande the case of permission , would you please explaine more .

Comment: In my case I use this scenario to get data from ULS logs and the user in this case should be local admin and get access to temp db in sql where SharePoint save temp data from ULS logs when PowerShell command run. In many cases when you get some data from SharePoint Using PowerShell command you should have some permission on sql or sharepoint. That's why I mentioned this.